# Why is the Sanctum Sanctorum called Garbha Griha?

Tags: temple, etymology

The place where the deity in a temple is placed (prathishtana) is in english called Sanctum Sanctorum.  We refer to it as Garbha Griha. The simple sanskrit meaning of this term is 'Home of the Womb' (Garbha = Womb Griha = Home).

My question: **Why is the Sanctum Sanctorum called Garbha Griha?**

To maake it amply clear I do not need an opinion based reply, but **"A reply substantiated by references to Itihasa Puranas, Vedas, smritis of such sources."**

Comment: what are so-called scriptures going to add to the common sense meaning - the core of the temple?